# trouble with execute command at cmd in java

Tags: java, command

i want to reboot my adsl modem and my code is this . the code is going well until it reach to login section and  i must enter username(admin) and press enter . problem is that `/c` is not work (`/c admin`). how i can write admin and press enter ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{

    String tel = "telnet 192.168.1.1 23";
    String user = "admin";
    String pass = "admin";
    String reboot = "reboot";
    String command = "cmd /c start cmd.exe /c"+tel;
    Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);


}
```

my mean of login section is this picture:

http://s1.postimg.org/eb74ryahb/Untitledsd.png

Answer (score 0):

```
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
Writer writer = new java.io.OutputStreamWriter(child.getOutputStream());
writer.append("string");
writer.flush();
```

After this you would read input again to see if it asks for password or whatever it does.

Comment: it doesn't work. it doesn't append `string ` to cursor in cmd .